# Как сделать кнопку, создающую новый элемент?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть скрол, внутри которого ConstraintLayout, в нём есть несколько edittext. Пожалуйста, помогите реализовать кнопку, по нажатию на которую будет создан в этом скроле точно такой же edittext под предыдущим (по последующему нажатию создастся ещё один и т.д.) И как сделать, чтобы название созданного edittext было соответствующим name1, name2, name3, ...

```
    <ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/scrollView2" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" 
android:background="@drawable/for_scroll" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnCount" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvKof"> 

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

<EditText 
android:id="@+id/name1" 
style="@style/ETon2Layout" 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_marginStart="15dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
android:background="@drawable/for_input" 
android:ems="10" 
android:hint="название" 
android:inputType="text" 
android:maxLength="30" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent" 
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".30" /> 

<EditText 
android:id="@+id/name2" 
style="@style/ETon2Layout" 
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_marginStart="15dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
android:background="@drawable/for_input" 
android:ems="10" 
android:hint="название" 
android:inputType="text" 
android:maxLength="30" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name1" 
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent" 
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".30" /> 
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в scrollView лежит не LinearLayout, а ConstraintLayout. Не указана ширина и высота EditTexto'ов. Соответственно придется поправить xml так:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/for_scroll"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnCount"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvKof">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name1"
            style="@style/ETon2Layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/for_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="название"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="30"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name2"
            style="@style/ETon2Layout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/for_input"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="название"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="30"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

java:

```
yourBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText newEditText = new EditText(this);
            newEditText.setTextAppearance(R.style.ETon2Layout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMarginStart(convertDpToPixels(15));
            layoutParams.setMargins(convertDpToPixels(15), convertDpToPixels(16), 0, 0);
            newEditText.setBackground(R.drawable.for_input);
            newEditText.setEms(10);
            newEditText.setHint("название");
            newEditText.setMaxLines(30);
            newEditText.setTag("name" + linearLayout.getChildCount());
            linearLayout.addView(newEditText);
        }

        public int convertDpToPixels(float dp) {
            return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    });
```

следует заменить **this** на context вашего приложения

Comment: Ширина у меня задана в процентах, а высота в style="@style/ETon2Layout"